# as.Date() not working with May or October dates

Tags: r

In the following code, I'm getting NA for dates involving "May" and "Oct". What am I missing here?

```
dates <- paste0("1", month.abb, "1960")
dates
#  [1] "1Jan1960" "1Feb1960" "1Mar1960" "1Apr1960" "1May1960" "1Jun1960" "1Jul1960" "1Aug1960" "1Sep1960" "1Oct1960" "1Nov1960" "1Dec1960"
as.Date(dates, format = "%d%b%Y")
#  [1] "1960-01-01" "1960-02-01" "1960-03-01" "1960-04-01" NA           "1960-06-01" "1960-07-01" "1960-08-01" "1960-09-01" NA           "1960-11-01" "1960-12-01"
```

Comment: Probably has to do with your local configurations, maybe "Oct" abbreviation is spelled differently in your local language.

Comment: Check `Sys.getlocale()`; mine is `LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8` and it works

Comment: Agree that is an issue related to the locale. Using my German locale ("de_DE.UTF-8") I can reproduce your issue. What I do in these cases. Temporarily switch the locale, e.g. `lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C"); as.Date(dates, format = "%d%b%Y"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)`

Comment: Thanks all. This was indeed related to the locale. Specifying English locale solves the issue.

Comment: this has to be a duplicate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `"LC_ALL"` to `"C"`. Just for current script, you can use `Sys.setlocale()`.

```
> invisible(Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'de_CH.UTF-8'))  ## you probably have "de_DE.UTF-8"
> as.Date('1May1960', format = "%d%b%Y")
[1] NA
> Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'C')
[1] "C"
> as.Date('1May1960', format = "%d%b%Y")
[1] "1960-05-01"
```

To make this permanent, edit/create `~/.Renviron` file with this entry:

```
LC_ALL=C
```

The *C* means setting identical to that of the C language, which is English.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is independent of locale. It is based on the fact that the built-in `month.abb` is always in English regardless of locale.

```
library(stringi)

x |>
  stri_replace_all_fixed(month.abb, paste0("-", 1:12, "-"),
    vectorize_all = FALSE) |>
  as.Date("%d-%m-%Y")
## [1] "2019-05-01"
```

### Note

Input

```
x <- "1May1960"
```

### Update

Fixed.